# Listing values in a range in chronological order

Tags: excel

So currently I have a column of dates (A) and a column of numerical values (B).

The dates are listed in ascending order in col A.
The values are listed in col B but not every date has a value.

In a separate column (E) I want to list the values in B in a list without the blanks, in other words just a list of the numerical values. I'm using the following array formula to do that in column E.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(B$10:B$1000,SMALL(IF(B$10:B$1000<>"",ROW(B$10:B$1000)-ROW(B$10)+1),ROWS(B$10:B10))),"")}
```

The formula looks down col. B starting at row 10 and whenever it finds a value, drops it in col. E and it works perfectly. The values are extracted in chronological order (and if I switch out SMALL for LARGE it reverses the list so the most recent are at the top).

However, I want to add a second column of numerical values in col. C. My question is - how can I adapt my current formula so it looks in both columns B and C rather than just B and continues to list them chronologically (in other words for each date, it looks in B and C before proceeding to the next date)?

I've tried adapting the formula to include an array,

```
B$10:C$1000
```

for example, but without success.

Comment: (1) What value should be picked for a particular date when there are values in both B and C? (2) Why not create col. D with (B or C) and lookup through D?

Comment: I would need values in B AND C to be retrieved and entered in E. In other words, two entries for the same date underneath each other.

Comment: Okay... Than concat values from B and C (if they exist) and place the result to D. Then apply your function to D. Maybe like this? :)

Comment: I'm willing to add an extra column in there if it helps.